# Unexpectedly large coefficients in logistic interaction model

Tags: r, regression, logistic, interaction

I would like to know if you could provide any insights regarding large and unexpected coefficients in logistic models with interaction terms.

When running the interaction model, the coefficients for the IVs without interaction take on values as high as -75 (significant). However, when I run the same model but without the interaction term, that same variable coefficient takes on the value 2.4 (significant, and in line with the theoretical expectation).

I'm mainly concerned about whether this means that something is wrong with the data or the model? Or is it normal that such coefficients are produced?

Three things things that might be worth noting:

1. Without the interaction term, the first IV, "lnfood" (food supply) has a negative impact on the DV (armed conflict onset), while the second, "polhi" (political inequalities) has a positive impact. I'm going to consider interaction plots to better understand the results.
2. The IVs are continuous and the DV is dichotomous.
3. The first IV, "lnfood", ranges between 7.2 and 8.3, while the second, "polhi", ranges between 0 and 0.98.

Here is the regression code, including control variables:

````
Model31 <- glm(onset3 ~ lnfood*polhi + democracy + lpopl + lgdpcapl2 + 
               peaceyears, family = "binomial")

summary(Model31)
#                Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)    8.58803    3.47251   2.473   0.013393 *  
# lnfood        -1.73106    0.47121  -3.674   0.000239 ***
# polhi        -74.51812   15.98647  -4.661   3.14e-06 ***
# democracy      0.01674    0.17503   0.096   0.923824    
# lpopl          0.56549    0.04692  12.053   < 2e-16 ***
# lgdpcapl2      0.03176    0.09650   0.329   0.742035    
# peaceyears    -0.26536    0.01206 -21.999   < 2e-16 ***
# lnfood:polhi   9.92313    2.05842   4.821   1.43e-06 *** 

```
````

Comment: Could you add plots of the fits?

Comment: When you run this model, do you get a warning that says numerical 0 or 1 predictions occurred?

Comment: This may be related to the different scale of the left inside variables. My suggestion is to scale the variables so that they all have the same 0 mean and unit stdev and see if the change remains so big or becomes more reasonable.. if you keep the predictors on a different scale then the coefficients are not directly comparable because the scale of the variables is not comparable as well

Comment: @Fr1 I agree, although the fact that the coefficient change vales by an order of magnitude when other variables are include or excluded indicates to me that this is a problem with overfitting and near perfect separation rather than just a matter of variable scale. It's true that a coefficient of 74 isn't troubling in itself because of the scaling of the variables. (I know I'm inclined to interpret coefficients as if they were standardized, and one has to be careful when doing that with raw coefficients.)

Comment: @Noah yes indeed it can be a problem due to overfitting, sure, and can be a problem due to multicollinearity of some kind.. that’s why to be sure it is overfitting then I usually try to scale and transform the predictors so that I can be sure that, if this happens, I can exclude that this is generated by other problems..

Comment: try to standardize the covariates and also use `vif` test.